# Android facebook graph Api GraphRequest.newMeRequest doesn't work

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in Android and I'm trying to use "Android facebook graph Api GraphRequest.newMeRequest",but my code doesn't work,the app crash when I'm logging.
Here's my code,maybe someone can help me.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    facebookSDKInitialize();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    getLoginDetails(loginButton);
}
/*
   Initialize the facebook sdk 
 */
protected void facebookSDKInitialize() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}
/*
Register a callback function with LoginButton to respond to the login result.
*/
protected void getLoginDetails(LoginButton login_button){
    // Callback registration
    login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult login_result) {
            getUserInfo(login_result);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // code for cancellation
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            //  code to handle error
        }
    });
}
/*To get the facebook user's own profile information via  creating a new request.*/
protected void getUserInfo(LoginResult login_result){
    GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            login_result.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject json_object,
                        GraphResponse response) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("jsondata",json_object.toString());

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    Bundle permission_param = new Bundle();
    permission_param.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.width(120).height(120)");
    data_request.setParameters(permission_param);
    data_request.executeAsync();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("data",data.toString());
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
    AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}
```

}

In Android Studio I get the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.novella.auto, PID: 11300
>                     Theme: themes:{}
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a
>   null object reference
>                         at com.example.novella.autofa.MainActivity$2.onCompleted(MainActivity.java:73)
>                         at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:304)
>                         at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1368)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5475)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

The error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference" refer to this string:

```
 intent.putExtra("jsondata",json_object.toString());
```

What I'm doing wrong?Please,help me! :)